# How to implement Executor Service of Excutors

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following scenario,
[image]

For every request on tomcat we need to get data from different machines(here we already had rest service on each machine) and as a response we send merged data of all responses from different machines to that request.
For this we implemented ExcuterServices as follows

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
      List<Future<Object>> results = executor.invokeAll(callables, 2000,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This need to do for every user request(and these request are >50 in number),this is getting difficult(creating 3Thread per request) and resources are limited.

Please suggest me how to implement design like pool of Executor Services where each ExceutorServices in a pool had 3threads and to delegate these request to pool of ExecutorServices.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont create a Thread or even ThreadPools on every request! Create one and reuse it or better have a look a micro services.

Answer (score 0):

Every request needs to get data from different machine and you are creating three threads per request. Then you are merging the output and then sending this response to the client who issued this request. Using multi-threading may be really a nice option if you have multiple processors or some of your tasks are I/O oriented.

> This need to do for every user request(and these request are >50 in
>   number),this is getting difficult(creating 3Thread per request) and
>   resources are limited.

It does not make sense to create three threads for each client request. You need to put some limit on the requests you want to process at a time (use benchmarking). You can keep all the requests in queue and process only that number at a time where each request can have its own `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Thanks akhil. For every request i must have to get data from 3 machines and until i didn't get response(or time out) from three machines i didn't have to send any response,how can i implement  design like these

Comment: @pydi you can either use invokeall or get future object after submission and use get to block until you get result

Comment: Akhil, i am doing same thing now,actual problem is i am creating ExecutorService object with three threads for every request, i want to know a way to create 10 ExecutorService(3 threads inside) objects and reuse these 10 ExecutorService objects for every request instead of creating new ExecutorService(with 3 threads) for every request.

Comment: But how do you join output from three threads from three executorservice? . It's better to use single executorservice.

Comment: ravindra, i am using one ExecutorSerivce with three threads, and joining these three threads out put as mentioned above, but this process is doing for each request, how can i maintain N ExecutorService objects so that i can delegate user request to these N ExecutorService objcets like a blocking Queue.

Answer (score 0):

> For this we implemented ExcuterServices as follows
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> This need to do for every user request(and these request are >50 in number),this is getting difficult(creating 3Thread per request)

Are you creating a new thread *pool* for each request?  If so, then don't do that.  Just create one global pool, and submit your three *tasks* to the pool for each request.  If you are anticipating a lot of requests, then the size of the pool (`numThreads`) should be about the same as the number of available CPU cores if the tasks are compute bound, or maybe more if they're going to spend time waiting to do I/O.  (You'll have to experiment to find the best number.)

---

If, on the other hand, I misread your question, and you already *are* creating just one thread pool, then your question doesn't make sense:  It's a *fixed* thread pool.  It will never have more than (or fewer than) the given `numThreads`.

---

> [If I use a thread pool, then] how can i get to know that these 3 threads are for request 1 and these 3 are for request 2...?

When you use an `ExecutorService`, you should not need to know the identities of the threads that execute your *tasks*.  The tasks themselves should know what to do.

Each task that you submit is an object that implements the `Callable` interface.  Whatever information the task needs to do its job should be provided to it through its constructor arguments.

> ...and also how can we known that those particular three threads finished?

Each time you submit a `Callable` instance to an `ExecutorService`, you get back a `Future` object.  You can use the `Future` object to find out whether the task is finished, to wait for it to finish, and to access a result that was returned by the task when it finished.

If you still have questions, then you probably should take some time to work your way through the Java Tutorial chapter on concurrency before doing anything else.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks James. If i create one global pool and i submit three tasks for that pool then i have to wait until these three tasks get data and this should be done for each request, will this increase response time?.

Comment: If i increased no.of threads in pool and delegate three threads for each request then how can i get to known that these 3 threads are for request 1 and these 3 are for request 2 and also how can we known that those particular three threads finished.

Comment: @Pydi see the additional info that I added to the end of my answer, above.